# Joomla 2.5 how can i change contents of wysiwyg editor using javascript

Tags: javascript, text, joomla2.5, wysiwyg

How can I change the contents of the joomla 2.5 wysiwyg textarea.

I can see there is a text area and an iframe but don't know how to change the contents so that the whole thing keeps working.

Ideally I'd like to use mootools

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  TinyMCE has a series of JS call you can make so I did:

```
textholder = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'});
var textholder2 = textholder.replace(/----TEXTTOREPLACE-----/g,idToUseIs);
tinymce.get('invoice').setContent(textholder2,{format : 'raw'});
```

The TEXTTOREPLACE was the text I wanted to replace when a user picked an option.

you can find full details here

[http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:class.tinymce.Editor](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aclass.tinymce.Editor)

Hope this helps - it took me 4 hours to track down the solution!